# init.d script for running second mysql server fails

Tags: linux, init.d, mysql

I have 2 mysql servers, one is set with all the mysql defaults (port,socket, etc.) and the second is set to port 3307 and a different socket with defaults file called my-dev.cnf .

when i run:

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my-dev.cnf
```

the server runs correctly

what i'm trying to do, is to have an init.d script to run it. I copied the /etc/init.d/mysqld script and changed the following line:

```
exec="/usr/bin/mysqld_safe"
```

to:

```
exec="/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my-dev.cnf"
```

but it keeps failing on:

```
[ -x $exec ] || exit 5
```

with:

> /etc/init.d/mysql-dev: line 63: [: '/usr/bin/mysqld_safe': binary operator expected

how can i make it work so it will use the defaults i set in /etc/my-dev.cnf?

thanks!

Comment: Off-topic or not, for those who end up here: duplicating an init.d script will fail on RHEL unless you set the `prog` environment variable to something fresh. In this case it would be "mysqld" by default but needs to be change to something different from the original script, such as "mysqld-dev". Otherwise it just refuses to load with no logs, errors, or any output or feedback whatsoever. This is passed to the `daemon` command later and *must* be unique or it thinks the service is already running. Not fun to work this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `[ -x ]` is testing if a file is executable, but the string is not an executable, it's your modified command line.

Paste the whole script on http://pastie.org , I will adapt it ;)

Comment: I pasted it: http://pastie.org/5032463. thanks!

Comment: thanks for the help! as you wrote, i was trying to pass params in the wrong place. I edited some of the vars in the file that are actually params for /usr/bin/mysqld_safe. thanks again

Comment: That should work : http://pastie.org/5034974